# React - Iterate through 2d array and compare current element to neighboring elements and their values

Tags: javascript, for-loop, multidimensional-array, iteration

I am attempting to iterate through a 2D array that serves as a game board. I need to iterate through each [x][y] element in the 2D array and then look at all of it's neighboring cells and determine if they contain a 1 or 0. I am making a John Conway Game of Life app and need to determine how many "alive" (neighboring cells in the 2D array that contain a 1) there are.

When I used nested for loops to iterate through the 2D array and try to compare the current cell to it's neighbors I run into an undefined error.

```
for(let x = 0; x < this.state.boardHeight; x++) {
        for(let y = 0; y < this.state.boardWidth; y++) {
          let neighborCount = 0;
          // Game of Life logic pertaining to squares being alive/dead
          neighborCount += oldBoard[x - 1][y - 1];
          neighborCount += oldBoard[x][y - 1];
          neighborCount += oldBoard[x + 1][y - 1];
          neighborCount += oldBoard[x - 1][y];
          neighborCount += oldBoard[x + 1][y];
          neighborCount += oldBoard[x - 1][y + 1];
          neighborCount += oldBoard[x][y + 1];
          neighborCount += oldBoard[x + 1][y + 1];

          console.log('neighborCount ' + neighborCount[x]);

          // If square has 2 live neighbors it stays alive
          if(neighborCount == 2) {
            newBoard[x][y] = oldBoard[x][y];
          }
          // If square has exactly 3 neighbors a new life square is born
          else if (neighborCount == 3) {
            newBoard[x][y] = 1;
          }
          // Is square has more than 3 live neighbors it dies
          else if(neighborCount > 3){
            newBoard[x][y] = 0;
          }
        }
       }
```

All of the `neighborCount += oldBoard[x][y]` lines of code returned undefined. What's the problem with how I am iterating and comparing?

```
Cannot read property '-1' of undefined
App._this.componentDidUpdate
/src/App.js:93:43
  90 | for(let y = 0; y < this.state.boardWidth; y++) {
  91 |   let neighborCount = 0;
  92 |   // Game of Life logic pertaining to squares being alive/dead
> 93 |   neighborCount += oldBoard[x - 1][y - 1];
     |                                   ^
  94 |   neighborCount += oldBoard[x][y - 1];
  95 |   neighborCount += oldBoard[x + 1][y - 1];
  96 |   neighborCount += oldBoard[x - 1][y];
```

That's the error I am getting. [Here is a Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Nicknyr/FCC_Game_Of_Life) with the entire program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in your error message: `Cannot read property '-1' of undefined`

Your code is starting at `x = 0, y = 0` and then the first line is trying to access `oldBoard[x - 1][y - 1]`, so what does that translate to?

Answer: `oldBoard[0 - 1][0 - 1]` which is `oldBoard[-1][-1]`

`oldBoard[-1]` evaluates to `undefined` so then it's essentially trying to do `undefined[-1]`, but `undefined` doesn't have a property named `-1`, so it throws an error.

You'll need to write your code in such a way that it doesn't try to look at invalid cells.

Comment: Good eye. I'm kind of new to React and was getting caught up on whether componentDidUpdate was doing what it was supposed to. Overlooked something simple.Thanks.